# What files does the Windows 7 upgrade disc look for?

Tags: windows-7, windows, upgrade

I have a valid copy of Windows XP and a purchased a Windows 7 upgrade disc.

I like to wipe my drive clean when reinstalling my OS. However, the upgrade disc fails to install if it doesn't find a valid copy of XP on the disc.

Rather than going through the trouble of installing XP and then installing 7, is there a way I can "spoof" an XP install by placing some key files and the upgrade disc looks for on the hard drive?

Answer (score 5):

Here are the instructions for a hack that claims it allows you to perform a Windows 7 install via an upgrade license on a formatted or blanked drive.

1. Boot up the PC with the Windows 7 Upgrade DVD disc media into DVD-ROM drive.
2. Follow the Windows 7 Install Wizard to install the operating system

   - During installation, when prompted for a product key, **DO NOT** enter a Product Key
3. Unselect the  check box for *Automatically activate Windows when I’m online* **during** the installation
4. Boot up to the desktop after Windows 7 finish installing
5. Activating Windows by one of the following options:

   - Manually enter the Windows 7 Upgrade Product Key to activate online
   - Activate via phone.

Note: The source of these steps are found [here](http://bit.ly/pUiwJ9). If the above fails, there are three workarounds at the source's page. Two of three doesn't require reinstalling Windows 7.

*Disclaimer: I haven't tested this. Use at your own risk.*

Comment: +1 as I was about to mention that site! Also some useful info here: http://www.winsupersite.com/article/win7/clean-install-windows-7-with-upgrade-media

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for hacks.  As explained in another SuperUser question that actually asks *about the goal and not the step* (["Is it possible to remove all partitions when upgrading from Windows XP to Windows 7?"](https://superuser.com/questions/325968/)), [the *official* Microsoft way to do this](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows7/help/upgrading-from-windows-xp-to-windows-7?T1=tab04) is to start the Windows 7 installer, and erase and re-create one's disc partitions *from within the setup utility*.

Comment: W7 Upgrade media will not allow a clean install to a blank hard drive. XP or Vista partition needs to be present before install will proceed.

Comment: He **doesn't** want to install an older version of Windows first. He wants to install Windows 7 via an *upgrade license* on a hard drive that's currently blanked -- no Windows.

Comment: The question does not say that, if you read it.  It says that xe _likes_ to do that, not that xe has actually yet done it.  There is an official Microsoft way to do what xe likes to do.